# adding digit after a group reference

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I have lines of data that includes two dates. I want to change the format of the first date from `mm/dd/yy` to `20yy-mm-dd`.
Since I want to change only the first date, I use `perl` instead of `sed`, because `sed` doesn't have lazy matching.

The following gives the wrong results

```sh
echo test,10/02/20,test2,11/03/20,test3 | perl -pe 's/(.*?)(..)\/(..)\/(..)(.*)/\120\4-\2-\3\5/'
# P20-10-02,test2,11/03/20,test3
```

If I add a space after `\1` it works fine, but I don't want that extra space in the output:

```sh
echo test,10/02/20,test2,11/03/20,test3 | perl -pe 's/(.*?)(..)\/(..)\/(..)(.*)/\1 20\4-\2-\3\5/'
# test, 2020-10-02,test2,11/03/20,test3
```

The problem seems to be that it reads `\120` not as \1 + 20 but as reference to group 120 (which doesn't exist).

Comment: It's been awhile since Perl wanted you to use the back reference notation (`\1`) in the replacement side. You wouldn't have received the `\1 better written as $1` warning because the `\120` is considered an octal character instead (capital "P") (see [toke.c](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/e935a39c197c3d6d97be7fa7623c451224180b68/toke.c#L3563)). Since the replacement side is a double quoted context, the double quote stuff happens first. The `\120` is already 'P' before Perl fills in the captures.

Comment: @RyszardCzech "backreference" was not a term I knew. So when I searched for an answer to my question I didn't find the answer you mentioned.

Comment: Moreover final regex in answer below didn't even need any technique like `${1}` i.e. `perl -pe 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})~20$3-$1-$2~' <<< "$s"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this *optimized* simpler regex for your case as you don't need to use more than 3 capture groups to avoid any digit after back-reference in substition:

```
perl -pe 's~(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})~20$3-$1-$2~' <<< "$s"
```

---

Your original regex can be solved using:

```
s='test,10/02/20,test2,11/03/20,test3'
perl -pe 's~(.*?)(..)/(..)/(..)(.*)~${1}20$4-$2-$3$5~' <<< "$s"
```

```
test,2020-10-02,test2,11/03/20,test3
```

Mark your back-reference as `${n}` instead of `$n` or `\n` when using digits next to them to mark your back-reference appropriately.

Comment: Bit of further tuning. You may replace `(..)` with `(\d{2})`

Comment: Or even `([0-9]{2})`. `\d` matches a whole bunch of characters you wouldn't expect to see in numeric dates in the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: Leading `(.*?)` and trailing `(.*)` are redundant. They do not do anything useful and only complicates the code.

Comment: That's right @TLP It can be done using `perl -pe 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})~20$3-$1-$2~' <<< "$s"`. I didn't attempt to optimize OP's regex but have added it now in answer.